# python workon command doesn't activate the virtual environment in cmd windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows-7, virtualenv

We are trying to install a django project in a remote server that is Windows 7. The installer make a virtual environment and install some packages in it, django among them. 
The virtual environment is created (I can see it typeing workon or lsvirtualenv) but is not activated if I type workon  in a cmd, simply prompts current path after press enter key
In which cases happen this? Why can't I activate a virtual environment that exists?
Note: This process finish successfuly in local machines

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried activate? My cmd usually looked like
`tutorial/scripts/activate`

Comment: Nope. But it is solved: added try/except clause in virtualenv.py to control exception in case of certains locales